# Why piece-wise definition of a function in Haskell depends on the order they specified?

Tags: haskell

Being a beginner, I am working on an example of the function with piece-wise definition.

```
pts 1 = 10
pts 2 = 6
pts x = x
```

The code above works as I expected. However, when I tried to change the order to

```
pts x = x
pts 1 = 10
pts 2 = 6
```

I got a warning

> warning: [-Woverlapping-patterns] Pattern match is redundant

and the last two statements look to be ignored by the compiler.
I did not manage to Google an answer, I would be grateful for a link to the explanation.

Comment: Writing an algorithm that checks whether all patterns are disjoint is hard, and writing patterns that are all disjoint is annoying. Therefore you must accept that some patterns overlap, and the language must specify what happens when they do. Trying them in the order the programmer wrote them is one natural choice; there are others, but most of them are *much* more complicated to specify and use correctly.

Comment: @DanielWagner your comment would make a good answer.

Comment: @DanielWagner I suppose it would be possible to automatically order patterns from most to least specific (though in less trivial examples it would require some kind of lexicographic convention). Only... _why_? The simple top-to-bottom works perfectly well and is easy to understand and debug.

Comment: @CalumHalpin Maybe. I'm uncertain. With these "why does X happen?" questions, there's always two levels of answer; there's "what is the rule that explains this behavior?" and there's "why was that rule chosen?". The existing accepted answer is an answer to the former, which makes me think that, while interesting, an answer to the latter wouldn't really be relevant to the original querent.

Comment: @DanielWagner it could well be relevant to someone coming across this question in the future though. In any case, it is an answer and doesn't belong in the comments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Haskell, patterns in function definitions like this are checked from top to bottom. So you first example is the same as:

```hs
pts x =
  if x == 1 then 10
  else if x == 2 then 6
  else x
```

And your second definition is similar to:

```hs
pts x =
  if True then x
  else if x == 1 then 10
  else if x == 2 then 6
  else undefined
```

Clearly, in this second example the first branch is always taken, the rest are redundant.

Answer (score 5):

Haskell goes through the patterns top-to-bottom and picks the first one that *matches* the input. In this case, `x` matches *any* input, because it's just a plain variable, so if this is on top it is *always* chosen immediately and the other patterns not even considered. It's this decision:

```
pts x = if True then x
         else if ... -- irrelevant
```

If it comes at the bottom, it is only considered after the other patterns have failed, and because these match specifically only a single number, that will happen more often than not.